# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS: Apps cannot find /usr/share/appdata

Tags: 20.04

I've not had much success with Ubuntu 20.04.  Aside from the base installation, I can't get Videos or VLC to work.  Videos fails with some obscure message about not being able to find the source, and while I installed VLC without error and made it the default application for playing DVDs, when I click on it, it complains that the folder "/usr/share/appdata" does not exist, when it clearly DOES exist and I can navigate to it.  I accidentally clicked on another installed application, not intending to run it, and got the same message.

The last Ubuntu distro I had experience with was 12.04, so it's been some time, but the basic problem I am having is that none of the apps I try to install run after installation.  I'm not seeing any lingering indication of installation failure.  I need a little help here.

Comment: What method are you using to install apps?  Is this a "clean" installation, or did you install over another version of Ubuntu? If you are getting "obscure messages" -- please copy/paste them here verbatim along with the steps you take to reproduce the message.

Comment: This was a clean install over a Windows 7 system.  The Videos app failed as soon as I tried to play a movie DVD with that "unknown source" message.  The VLC app failed following installation saying it couldn't open "/usr/share/appdata".  I lost patience at this point and uninstalled both Videos and VLC.  Then I reinstalled VLC, and rebooted the system afterwards.  Now VLC seems to work, but I should not have had to jump through all these hoops to GET it to work.  Because I uninstalled Videos, I can no longer post the message I ws receiving unless you can tell me if it's in a log somewhere.

Comment: As to how I'm installing apps, I use the Ubuntu Software icon.

Comment: The method of installing Ubuntu 20.04 LTS was  to download the ISO, burn it to a DVD, then boot from the DVD and do a clean install.  Should have worked - should have wound up with a functioning pristine environment.